# Difference between two methods for OpenMP parallel

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, race-condition

I just want to evaluate an integration of function by summarization by OpenMP by using an array to hold every values computed in every step > take sum of all values; and take sum without the array.

The code is:

```
double f(double x)
{
    return sin(x)*sin(x)/(x*x+1);
}
```

**METHOD 1**

```
    long i = 0;
    const long NUM_STEP = 100000;
    double sum[NUM_STEP];
    double from = 0.0, to = 1.0;
    double step = (to - from)/NUM_STEP;
    double result = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(sum) num_threads(4)
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
        sum[i] = step*f(from+i*step);
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
        result += sum[i];
    printf("%lf", result);
```

**METHOD 2**

```
    long i = 0;
    const long NUM_STEP = 100000;
    double from = 0.0, to = 1.0;
    double step = (to - from)/NUM_STEP;
    double result = 0;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared(result) num_threads(4)
    for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
        result += step*f(from+i*step);
    printf("%lf", result);
```

But the results are too different. The METHOD 1 gave an stable value, but the METHOD 2 gave a changable value. Here is an example:

METHOD 1: 0.178446

METHOD 2: 0.158738

The value of METHOD 1 is true (checked by another tool).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** The first method does not have a *race-condition* whereas the second method has.

The first method does not have a race-condition whereas the second method has. Namely, in the first method:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(sum) num_threads(4)
for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
    sum[i] = step*f(from+i*step);
for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
    result += sum[i];
```

each thread saves the result of the operation `step*f(from+i*step);` in a different position of the array `sum[i]`. And after that the *master* thread, sequentially reduces the values saved on the array `sum`, namely:

```
for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
    result += sum[i];
```

Actually, there is a slight improvement that you can make on this version; instead of allocating the array `sum` with the same size as the number of `NUM_STEP`, you can just allocated it with the same size as the number of threads, and each thread would save in a position equals to its `ID`, namely:

```
int total_threads = 4;
double sum[total_threads];
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(total_threads)
{
  int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
  for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
      sum[thread_id] += step*f(from+i*step);
  for(i=0; i< total_threads; i++)
      result += sum[i];
}
```

Nonetheless, the best approach will be to actually fix the second method.

On the second method there is a *race-condition* on the update of the variable `result`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(result) num_threads(4)
for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
    result += step*f(from+i*step);
```

because the `result` variable is being updated concurrently by multiple threads in a non-thread safety manner.

To solve this *race-condition* you need to use the [reduction](http://jakascorner.com/blog/2016/06/omp-for-reduction.html) clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:result) num_threads(4)
for(i=0; i<NUM_STEP; i++)
    result += step*f(from+i*step);
```